# How to set multiple greater than sign in bquote

Tags: r

I'm trying to write an expression in R like this:

`bquote(lambda[50>x>=5])`

However, I got error:

`Unexpected '>=' in ...`

Is there anyway to deal with it?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
quote(lambda[50 > {x >= 5}])
```

e.g.

```
plot(0, main = quote(lambda[50 > {x >= 5}]))
```

[image]